Who was Gaudapada's guru?
Gaudapada is known to be the guru of Govindapada and the grand-guru of Adi Shankara. Who was his (Gaudapada's) guru?

Vyasa's son shuka is the guru of gaudapada

@CracklingCyclone references?

As per Śaṅkaravijayas, Gauḍapāda was the śiṣya of Śuka.
